# How to find the sum of an infinite fractional equation on an interval?

Tags: java, math

i am trying to find the summ of an equation:
S = -(2x)^2/2! + (2x)^4/4! - (2x)^6/6! + (2x)^8/8!....

the interval of x is [0.1;1.5]

There is another equation that is in this code 2(cos^2  − 1) however this outputs the correct answer.
What is wrong in this code?

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("x=");
    double x = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.close();
    if (x < 0.1 || x > 1.5) {
      System.out.println("error");
      return;
    }

    double s = -((2*x)*x/2) ;
    double a = (2*x)*x ;  
    int i = 2;    

    while (Math.abs(a) > 0.001) {
      a = -a*4*(x*x) ;   
      s = s + a/(i*(i-1));  
      i = i + 2;  
    }
    System.out.printf("function=%.4f%n", 2*(Math.cos(x)*Math.cos(x)-1));
    System.out.printf("summa=%.4f", s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1/

`(2*x)*x/2 == 2*x*x/2 == x*x`

same `(2*x)*x == 2*x*x` no need of parenthesis.

2/

'a' isn't lowering if 'x' is greater or equal 0.5 so he won't meet the condition to exit the loop.

3/
I guess the loop condition is that the current power division by factorial is less than 0.001.

```
double i = 2; // double for getting the rest too in the division
int neg = -1;
double pow;
double pow_res;
double res = 0;
double loop_check = 1;
while (loop_check > 0.001 || i < 99999) {
    pow = i - 1;
    pow_res = 2 * x;
    while (--pow != 0)  // get power result for 2X^n
        pow_res = pow_res *(2 * x);
    loop_check = pow_res / (i * ((i + 1) / 2)); // save the result for loop check and used after for calculation
    res = res + neg * loop_check;
    i = i + 2;
    neg = -neg;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for some reason. That while (--pow) is trying to convert a double into a boolean :/

Comment: my bad, I checked again, should be ook now. (forgot that numeric value aren't well interpreted in loop condition statement)